# How can I query Entity Framework to a different class and get a count instead of a list property?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Let's take an example model:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<Guitar> Guitars {get; set;}
}

public class Guitar
{
    public string Brand {get; set;}
    public string Model {get; set;}
}
```

I need to create a View with a list of all People and a count of how many guitars they have. To do that I would like to pass a ViewModel like this one populated with EF without loading all Guitards:

```
// This will be send to the View, I can also just send a List
public class ViewModelPassed
{
    List<PeopleGuitarViewModel> AllPeople { get; set; }
}

// This should be populated from EF
public class PeopleGuitarViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfGuitars { get; set; }
}
```

Can I query `EF` to a different class, and avoid bringing the whole list of guitars and instead get a `COUNT` in `SQL`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide primary key to your models for EF core to create the relationship:

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Guitar> Guitars { get; set; }
}
public class Guitar
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
}
```

Also use `public` for `AllPeople` property in `ViewModelPassed`:

```
public List<PeopleGuitarViewModel> AllPeople { get; set; }
```

Then query like :

```
ViewModelPassed modelPassed = new ViewModelPassed();
modelPassed.AllPeople = new List<PeopleGuitarViewModel>();
modelPassed.AllPeople = _applicationDbContext.Persons.Select(x =>
    new PeopleGuitarViewModel
    {
        Name = x.Name,

        NumberOfGuitars = x.Guitars.Count
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to do it like this:

```
var viewModel=context.Persons.Select(x=>new PeopleGuitarViewModel
{
  Name=x.Name,
  NumberOfGuitars=Guitars.Count()
}).ToList();
```

this kind of query is also named `Projection` and is consider best practice (do not send full entity to the view).

There are 2 libraries which I often use for such projections: AutoMapper and/or Mapster.

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

When populating your ViewModel, you can use Linq to get the count. Like this:

```
PeopleGuitarViewModel p= new PeopleGuitarViewModel();
p.Name = person.Name;
p.NumberOfGuitars = person.Guitars.Count;
```

Where person is an object of your Person class.